# HTTP to HTTPS on NGINX Django server

Tags: django, nginx

I'm setting up a server on AWS from a Django project and my Nginx gives an error when trying to switch from HTTP to HTTPS.
See my file:

`host = fantasy name`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  host;
    return 301 https://host$request_uri;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /staticfiles/ {alias  /home/ubuntu/Filmes/staticfiles/;}

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
```

Indeed when using the old domain over HTTP I am redirected to HTTPS but I get `CONNECTION DENIED TO THIS DNS`.

Comment: check this [article](https://realpython.com/django-nginx-gunicorn/#making-your-site-production-ready-with-https)

Comment: As I imagined. I have to create a certification, but `certbot` doesn't allow it due to the domain being uncommon. It's a test server. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: you can use **HTTPS * for local development  if you want to test your web app check it [here](https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to Turn on **HTTPS** and access your site over HTTPS, you’ll need an `SSL/TLS` certificate that sits on your web server . you can get a certificate from a Certificate Authority (CA)  like  [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) which is free

Comment: You were perfect in the placement, but Let's Encrypt does not allow addresses the same as AWS generates (because it is a free trial). But when it's really on the air, I'll do it. Thanks